# Help with iOS app crashing with “Out Of Memory”

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, xamarin.ios

I have an iPhone/iPad application made in MonoTouch, which is already in the apple store. However there's still an issue that hasn't been completely solved. I need to be able to upload large files to our servers. Sizes can vary from 2-100 Mb in size. I have tried several approaches:

1. Using SOAP Web Services, sending the byte array: a) Sending the whole file. Crashed. b) Splitting in chunks of 1Mb. Crashed after 10-15 chunks (varies).
2. Using WebClient.UploadFile. Works most of the time with smaller files < 5 Mb, but every now and then it crashes and everything larger than 10-12 Mb crashes. On the server, I have a aspx page that receives the information sent through a POST

Here is the actual code from the device:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient ();
string sLFN = sLocalFileName;
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo (sLFN)
string sUri = getUri ();
byte [] f = wc.UploadFile (sUri, sLFN)
```

I believe that the memory capacity of the iPhone / iPad is something that directly affects this.

Does anybody has any recomendation or suggested approach that I should follow?

Thanks in advance

Edgar Herrador

Comment: Hi Edgar. Did you ever resolve this issue. Because I am using *WebClient.UploadFile* in one of my applications and it is working correctly with most of my clients, but one client is reporting that the application is crashing at the point of sending over the files. The files being sent are photos taken on the *iPad*, so they are a lot less than 5Mb in size, and yet it is somehow still going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Streaming & Chunking. You're probably exceeding the message size when passing large files.

Are you getting any exceptions ?

Comment: That was my first approach: splitting in chunks of 1Mb. Crashed after 10-15 chunks.

Comment: Hi Edgar, did you get any exceptions ? What's your server side method of handling the files? is it WCF based? do you use streaming ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WCF streaming (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)?